# iframe opening a new browser window on post-back in Dynamics CRM

Tags: asp.net, iframe, dynamics-crm

i trying to add some costume app into Dynamics CRM

basically i have an ASP.Net Page i show within an iframe inside the MS CRM.
when i try to do a submit using a button it opens a new window and shows the result there, i want it to stay in the iframe.
help.

this is the ASP.Net code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" target="_self">
    <asp:Calendar ID="FromCalendar" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="ToCalendar" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/bdf52a59-5751-4ada-8704-056bfec5e625